# How to get back the /var/lib/dkpg folder?

Tags: dpkg

My friend deleted the `/var/lib/dkpg` folder of his 12.04 installation. Without it apt-get is not working. I'm new to Ubuntu and don't know much. How do I get it back?

Comment: Try `mkdir` it. I guess it right!!

Comment: @shgnInc - run `ls /var/lib/dpkg`, there is more to it than that. user237285 why would your friend remove the folder?

Comment: I would say install `dpkg`, but that is what installs software. I fear a reinstall may be in order.

Comment: @wilf, i hope, by `mkdir` it. ubutnu add the folders and files in it by `apt-get update`

Comment: @Dillmo -  but it won't work without `dpkg`...

Comment: @shgnInc - just experimenting, and no, that doesn't as that just updates the package cache.

Comment: @user237285 - you are using Ubuntu 12.04, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @wilf My friend is also new to ubuntu...we had some trouble installing flash player plugin and he removed the folder

Comment: @wilf Which is exactly why you can't install software. Installing `dpkg` needs `dpkg`, so you need to do so from an environment that already has it: the installation CD.

Comment: @Dillmo - it needs to read the `status` file in that directory, and needs to lock& unlock the `lock` file. Does your computer happen to run 12.04? I only have one with 13.10...

Comment: Try downloading your Ubuntu version of dpkg from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg , extract it. Then use `sudo cp -r ` to copy the needed files.

Comment: @Sneetsher - you can get the .deb from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/dpkg/download), but what is needed is a valid `status` file, with the packages listed [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/dpkg) as its contents. Then `dpkg` can be reinstalled. Also, the files need valid permissions.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 - why the edits?

Comment: @wilf review queuing; http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7245/version-tags-are-being-used-improperly-what-to-do

Comment: @wilf Sometimes I edit something and then notice something else I missed, and when I haven't had coffee yet it happens multiple times in a row. I'm all done now though.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 - Ok then - my answer works in 13.10, do you think it'll work in 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

Run these:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo sh -c "echo >> /var/lib/dpkg/lock"
sudo sh -c "echo >> /var/lib/dpkg/available"
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/parts
sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/updates
```

This will hopefully restore the necessary files, albeit some package errors may occur from recent transactions, as the `status` will not be up to date.

You can then test `apt-get` for any errors:

```
sudo apt-get install sl
```

<sub>You may need to update the package cache first with `sudo apt-get update`</sub>

`sl` is a small program that basically just shows a steam train in the terminal for when you mistype `ls`, but I have included it here as it is small, and unlikely to be installed ;-)